# getting the value from dropdownlist and saving it into database and if that is already present then showing some message

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Hi i have a drop down list and I want value from that list to be saved into database here is my action method in the controller class

```
public ActionResult NewRequest(Bookinfo bookinfo)
    {

        using (var db = new Database1Entities1())
        {

            return View(db.Bookinfoes.ToList());
        }

    }
```

and here is my view with drop down list

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication.Models.Bookinfo>
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "NewRequest";
 }

  <h2>NewRequest</h2>

<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Bookname", Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.Bookname, Value = m.Bookname }).ToList())
    </td>
    @*<td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Authorname", Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.Authorname, Value = m.Authorname }).ToList())
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownList("Publishername", Model.Select(m => new SelectListItem() { Text = m.Publishername, Value = m.Publishername }).ToList())
    </td>
    <td> </td>*@
</tr>
<tr> <td> <input type = submit value="Reserve" name="Reserve"></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to save the value in a table called issued which denotes that book is issued with the current date and if the book is already there i would like to show some message

Here is my database structure or rather structure of the Issued table

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Issued] (
  [BookId]  INT      NOT NULL,
  [date]    DATETIME NOT NULL,
  [IssueID] INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookId] ASC),
  FOREIGN KEY ([BookId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bookinfo] ([Id])
   };
```

Comment: It is irrelevant that you're using dropdowns. Please include your database structure.

Comment: I have displayed my table structure. Please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to make the database catch this sort of error.

Make your field `Issued.BookId` unique by adding the statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Issued] (
    [BookId]  INT      NOT NULL,
    [date]    DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [IssueID] INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BookId] ASC),
    FOREIGN KEY ([BookId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bookinfo] ([Id])
    CONSTRAINT AK_IssueId UNIQUE(IssueId) 
};
```

Then, when you attempt to add a new record to `Issued` for the same `BookId`, the `SqlException` will be thrown. Catch this exception and display your error message.

Comment: thats not what i want. See I am new to html and asp.net. i want to know whether I have to include a html.beginform in order for the submit button to work and when I am giving a name to the button then does that mean that it redirects to the controller of the same name ?? And if it does then how I get the value from drop down list to that controller?

Comment: You could look for some tutorials on ASP.NET MVC 4 to get the basics done. Anyway, you do need an `@Html.BeginForm()` to make submit button work; the argument of `BeginForm()` determines which method of the controller is called on submit; the first argument of `Html.DropDownList()` is the field name, so you can make your new method to be `ReserveBook(string Bookname, string Authorname, string Publishername)` and the parameters will get populated automatically

Comment: If the arguement of beginform() determines which method is called then what is name used for in the submit button??  Does it signify the controller??

Comment: No. Both controller and action (function name) are specified in `Html.BeginForm()`. It is `Html.BeginForm(actionName, controllerName, ...)` . The submit button name doesn't participate in routing at all, you can set any name or omit it altogether.

Comment: But I strongly recommend you to read some articles on this. Neither HTML nor ASP.NET MVC are intuitive to understand. At the very least, you need to know exactly how HTTP form work and how is MVC routing and model binding happens.